# SignedData giving Invalid algorithm specified.exception

Tags: c#, x509certificate, sha256, x509certificate2, pfx

I tried to sign and valid my signed data using myCert.pfx file private and public key. But while signing the data I am getting " Invalid algorithm specified." exception

.Net framework we are using is 4.5 and the code is as below

```
public static void CallMainMethod()
{
    string str = "Sign and verify the data";
    X509Certificate2 certificate = LoadPrivateKey();

    byte[] hashBytes = GetDataHash(str);
    byte[] signature = GetDigitalSignature(hashBytes);
} 

 private static X509Certificate2 LoadPrivateKey()
{
    return new X509Certificate2(@"d:\Keys\myCert.pfx", "Pass#@123");
}

 private static byte[]  GetDataHash(string sampleData)
{
    //choose any hash algorithm
    SHA256Managed managedHash = new SHA256Managed();
    return managedHash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sampleData));
}

private static byte[] GetDigitalSignature(byte[] data)
{
    X509Certificate2 certificate = LoadPrivateKey();
    RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;   
    return provider.SignHash(data, "SHA256");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that legacy `RSACryptoServiceProvider` doesn't support SHA2 algorithms. Rewrite last method as follows:

```
private static byte[] GetDigitalSignature(byte[] data)
{
    X509Certificate2 certificate = LoadPrivateKey();
    RSA provider = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();   
    return provider.SignHash(data, "SHA256", RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
}
```

This style is preferred as of .NET Framework 4.6 and above (@bartonjs, please correct me if I'm wrong in regards to .NET version).

Comment: Our current .NET framework is 4.5, does it have any alternate to make it work in Framework 4.5.

Comment: Only via CryptoAPI interop. Not directly through .NET API.

Comment: Yep, .NET Framework 4.6. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.getrsaprivatekey?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to)

Answer (score 0):

While @Crypt32 gave the best answer (upgrade to .NET Framework 4.6 or better and use `GetRSAPrivateKey()` and the better version of `SignData` -- it's been out over 4 years at this point), if you really need to stay on net45, your easiest answer is to open the PFX with X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable and copy the key into a better provider.

```
return new X509Certificate2(@"d:\Keys\myCert.pfx", "Pass#@123", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

...

```
RSA legacyProv = (RSA)certificate.PrivateKey;
RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
provider.ImportParameters(legacyProv.ExportParameters(true));
return provider.SignHash(data, "SHA256");
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `RSACng` class instead of `RSACryptoServiceProvider`?

Comment: @Crypt32 RSACryptoServiceProvider can do SHA-2-256 signatures... as long as it uses the correct provider type (24) and provider (Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider).  PFX imports tend to be one of the older provider names, which is why it fails.  That, and RSACng doesn't exist in net45 :).  (New in net46).

Comment: OK, thanks for clarification. In older versions I use interop and didn't know about this way. But this won't work for certs installed in cert store with non-exportable key, I assume.

Comment: @Crypt32 Correct. One can reopen the key using prov 24, but people frequently write it too fragile to handle 3rd party / HSM providers reliably. Since there was a PFX load here I went with the easier workaround.